# Conditional offer terms

Tags: job-offer, job-change, united-kingdom

Been offered a role at very high profile corporate brand, where in the offer email it’s explicitly stated that **confirmation of start date is sent subject to terms and conditions.**

A confirmation start date has been sent but a couple of t and c have not been asked for:

- Security clearance
- References

I am finding this odd since I’ve always been asked to provide this in the past when working in a corporate but here it doesn’t seem to be the case.

I’ve repeatedly asked hr if they are required and have they’ve told me the only thing pending is Id which I sent before getting confirmation email.

Is whether or not asking all done at company discretion, and is it fair to say my offer is now unconditional since I’ve been given a start date.

Thanks

Comment: Almost all corporate jobs don't require "security clearance" so that isn't unusual.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked, it doesn’t seem the case here either. They didn’t ask for references though, which I found odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the offer email it’s explicitly stated that confirmation of start
>   date is sent subject to terms and conditions.

If you are still concerned, contact the company and ask them specifically "Are there any remaining terms and conditions that must be satisfied?"

> Is whether or not asking all done at company discretion, and is it
>   fair to say my offer is now unconditional since I’ve been given a
>   start date.

If the company says they have everything they need, then it is done. The offer is unconditional.

Comment: It's definitely conditioned on OP showing up to work on the first day, producing the legally-required paperwork proving authorization to work, and signing the various employment agreements.

Comment: That's incorrectly summarizing my comment and you know it. I should have also mentioned "and passing a drug screen".  Also I don't believe that having a start date selected implies that there's no background check still ongoing.  I suppose to be pedantic, the applicant will be employed if they show up to work with evidence of their authorization to work, even if they fail any of the other factors, because the company will have to pay them for that first day.  But they wouldn't have a job, just a one day paycheck.

Comment: To confirm there is no drug screening! It also specifically says on the offer that start date is confirmed once t and cs have passed. I will very mislead if this is not the case and it is still conditional given I have just resigned from my very secure job. As Joe has said I also repeatedly asked about pre reqs, they didnt request either of the above.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suspect that this might be the UK from some of the language "security clearance" for example.

Comment: @Neuromancer: AFAIK that has a lot more to do with the industry sector and projects than country.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I think maybe we're seeing it differently because of the word the OP has chosen.  Normally a sure offer is said to be "firm" rather than "unconditional".  Not that there are no further conditions, but that they are within the applicant's control.

Comment: That’s what I meant, firm offer!

Comment: Neuromancer, yes it’s the UK

Comment: HR have told me that there is nothing else pending Joe, but I don’t feel convinced given references were not asked which is odd for an org this size and prestigious.

Comment: @BenVoigt in the uk apart from a very small number of safety related jobs pre entry drug testing is unknown out side of SC or DV clearance